# Some Terminology in Multilevel Analysis

Tags: regression, self-study, interaction, multilevel-analysis, terminology

What is the meaning of the following **terms** in *multilevel analysis*:

- cross-level interaction;
- micro level;
- macro level?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Micro level** refers to *lower level* in the model, usually it's an *individual level*.

**Macro level** refers to *higher level* in the model, usually it's a *group level*.

**Cross-level interaction** refers to "interaction between higher level and lower level
variables — that is, to modification of the effects of lower level variables by characteristics of the higher level units to which the lower level units belong (or vice versa)" (Diez Roux, 2002, p. 589).

**References**

Diez Roux, A. V. (2002). A glossary for multilevel analysis. *Journal of Epidemiology Community Health, 56*, 588-594. doi:10.1136/jech.56.8.588 Retrieved from http://jech.bmj.com/content/56/8/588.full.pdf